# jQuery AJAX function causing page to load multiple times when executed more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, event-listener

I'm using a jQuery function to dynamically load content into a page - an AJAX call.

There are four pages that need to load depending on the content that is clicked - basically a nav bar driven by AJAX calls. The problem is that after the first call, the pages start to load multiple times for one call, loading more times with each call on the page. Why is this happening?

This code is running in Statamic.

Here is the JS code:

```
//jQuery AJAX for subpages
var verticals = document.getElementsByClassName('verticals');
verticals = verticals[0].childNodes[3].childNodes[1].childNodes[1];
var url = verticals.getElementsByTagName('a');

document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
    var validate = event.target.id;
    var target = event.target.getAttribute('name');
    if(validate == 'subnav') {
        $('#populate').load(target);
    }
}, true);
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="verticals">
  <div class="arrow-wrap show-for-medium-up">
    <div class="arrow"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="show-for-medium-up v-nav">
      <div class="small-12 columns">
        <ul class="small-block-grid-5">
          {{ nav from="/{segment_1}/{segment_2}" }}
            <li><a id="subnav" name="{{ url }}">{{ title }}</a></li>
          {{ /nav }}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="small-12 columns show-for-small">
      <a href="#" class="button" data-dropdown="drop">Industries Served</a>
       <ul id="drop" class="f-dropdown" data-dropdown-content>
        {{ nav from="/{segment_1}/{segment_2}" }}

          <li><a id="subnav" name="{{ url }}">{{ title }}</a></li>

        {{ /nav }}
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="populate"></div>
```

Comment: Can you share the corresponding `HTML`..?

Comment: did u try with other listeners ?

Comment: It looks like your 'verticals' are hrefs, so on mouseup, the browser is following the links. Try adding `event.preventDefault();` to the `addEventListener()` function.

Comment: Sure, I'll include the corresponding HTML. 

The verticals, which follow the dom down to <a> tags, are actually pulling a name attribute, not an href. Does your advice still apply, beercodebeer?

Comment: What wraps the code you have provided? could that code be getting executed multiple times, resulting in multiple events being bound?

Comment: @KevinB Nothing wraps the JS. The HTML is wrapped by more html tags, but since the event in question is using AJAX, and is the only AJAX function thus far on the site, I doubt there are any conflicts.

Comment: Add an alert or console.log before the addEventListener line to be sure.

Comment: Is there any Javascript in the content being loaded?

Comment: I've figured it out. Can I submit my own solution on here?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

The Javascript library was being imported multiple times by Statamic due to the use of an alternative template file with repeat (unnecessary) code. Removing that code solved the problem.

So KevinB was pretty close with his suggestion.

Thanks guys!